# Need help using Git Lab to deploy me Angular9 app to Firebase using the .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: angular, firebase, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

**Tech Stack:** Angular9, GitLab, .gitlab-ci.yml, Firebase.

I already have a basic angular 9 app created and a Firebase project setup to deploy too.

I need to make sure my .gitlab-ci.yml is set up to deploy the angular9 app to Firebase.

Everything in the following .gitlab-ci.yml file works apart from the stage called: 'deploy'.

**This is the full .gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - linters
  - unit
  - e2e
  - build
  - deploy

.environment:
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - cache/Cypress
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  image: cypress/base:10
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

Run Prettier, Linting & Test Build:
  extends: .environment
  stage: linters
  script: |
    npm ci
    npm run lint
    npm run prettify-check

Unit Tests:
  extends: .environment
  stage: unit
  script: |
    npm ci
    npm run test:cli

Cypress Tests1:
  extends: .environment
  stage: e2e
  script: |
    npm ci
    chmod +x set-up-cypress.sh
    npx start-server-and-test start http://localhost:4200 cy:test1
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 1 day

Cypress Tests2:
  extends: .environment
  stage: e2e
  script: |
    npm ci
    chmod +x set-up-cypress.sh
    npx start-server-and-test start http://localhost:4200 cy:test2
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 1 day

Release build:
  extends: .environment
  stage: build 
  script: |
    npm ci
    npm run build --prod --aot

Deploy Job:
  extends: .environment
  stage: deploy 
  script: |
    npm ci
    npm run build --prod --aot
    npm install -g firebase-tools
    firebase use --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY production
    firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
  artifacts:
    name: "app"
    paths:
      - dist/app
```

**The only stage not working is the Deploy Job:**

```
 Deploy Job:
      extends: .environment
      stage: deploy 
      script: |
        npm ci
        npm run build --prod --aot
        npm install -g firebase-tools
        firebase use --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY production
        firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
      artifacts:
        name: "app"
        paths:
          - dist/app
```

**Note:** I've added the variable **$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY** to my Git Lab CI Variables.

**This is the error I get:** error: option '--token ' argument missing

**It seems to fail on this line of the yaml file: "firebase use --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY production"**

**This is my .firebaserc file:**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "training-fc63b",
    "production": "training-fc63b"
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but can you echo out the `FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN` in the deploy job? (and then revoke it if you do see it?) How have you added the variable? as `$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY` or `FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY`? did you set the state as `protected` or `masked`?

Comment: I added as FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY in gitlab as it doesnt allow $ and its not protected or masked currently

Comment: I just started to get this error as well. I don't run `firebase use`. It fails on `firebase deploy` in my case.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev what does your yaml look like? for the stage of firebase deploy?

Comment: Its `script` step is quite simple and standard: `firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN` And it fails with the same error